# chess probability placing 6 rooks , 2 on black squares and the other 4 on the white

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question is as the title says , we need to place 2 rooks on the black squares and the rest on the white.

My attempt , I tried first picking 2 rooks out of 6 then picking 2 black squares out of 32 for them then picking 4 out of the 4 rooks left and multiplying by 4 out of 32 white circles and our $Ω$ is 6 out of 64 since we need 6 squares for the 6 rooks out of the total 64 squares so my attempt was  $\frac {{6 \choose 2}{32 \choose 2} {4\choose 4}{32\choose 4}} {64 \choose 6}$ which is wrong, according to the book it should be $\frac {{32 \choose 2} {32\choose 4}} {64 \choose 6}$ but it has no explanation on why it is like that.

and I am failing to understand it don't we need to pick the 2 rooks on the black squares first?

Comment: Why ${6 \choose 2}$ in the beginning? Without further info, you should assume them to be indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Pick two rooks out of 6*"

The rooks are indistinguishable.  There is effectively only one way in which we can do this step, not $\binom{6}{2}$ ways.  The denominator treats the rooks as indistinguishable as well with the $\binom{64}{6}$.

It doesn't really matter whether we treated the rooks as distinguishable or indistinguishable so long as we are consistent in how we treat them.  If the denominator treats them as indistinguishable then the numerator should treat them the same way too.

Removing the erroneous $\binom{6}{2}$ (*and unnecessary $\binom{4}{4}$*) you will find that your answer then matches the book's.

---

If you were to treat the rooks as distinguishable, then in reality we have $64\frac{6}{~}=\binom{64}{6}\cdot 6! = 64\cdot 63\cdot 62\cdot 61\cdot 60\cdot 59$ ways in which we can place the rooks.

The numerator would have been to choose the black spaces occupied, choose the white spaces occupied, and then choosing which rook it was in which space in $\binom{32}{4}\binom{32}{2}\cdot 6!$ ways, or if you insisted on breaking them up first in $\binom{32}{4}\binom{32}{2}\binom{6}{4}4!\binom{2}{2}2!$ ways leading to the same final answer as if we treated them as indistinguishable